# Get all parents from a child

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, categories

Hellow, i have a simple table like:

```
CAT ID PARENT_ID
------+----------
   1      0
   2      0
   3      1
   4      1
   5      3
   6      2
```

I achieved to make a category tree, BUT i need something like this:

- Cat 1
- Cat 1-->SubCat 1
- Cat 1-->SubCat 2
- Cat 1-->SubCat 2-->SubCat1
- Cat 2
- Cat 2 --> SubCat1

I have this with my code:

```
Cat 1
Subcat1
SubCat2
SubSubcat1
Cat 2
Subcat1
```

I need to print the full parents path for every category.

Heres my code:

```
    <?php

require_once 'config.php';
?>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?php

$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "xxxx";
$databasename = "xxx";
$parent_id = 0;
$salida = " ";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
$ruta = "";


//connect to mysql and select db
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if (!empty($conn->connect_errno)) {
    die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

echo "<select>";
echo "<option value='' disabled selected>--Seleccione CategorÃ­a--</option>";

//call the recursive function to print category listing
category_tree(0);

echo "</select>";

//
//echo gettheparent(168);
//Recursive php function

function category_tree($catid) {

    global $conn;
    $sql = "select * from oc_category where parent_id ='" . $catid . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
        $i = 0;
//$ruta=gettheparent(168);    
        if ($i == 0) {

            echo "<option value='" . $row->category_id;
            echo "'>" . getthename($row->category_id);
            category_tree($row->category_id);
            echo "</option>";

            $i++;
        }
        if ($i > 0) {
            //echo '</ul>';
            //$ruta=gettheparent($catid);    
        }

    endwhile;
}



function getthename($category_id) {
    if ($category_id != 0) {
        $username = "xxxx";
        $password = "xxxxx";
        $hostname = "xxxx";
        $databasename = "xxxxx";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $query = "SELECT name FROM oc_category_description WHERE category_id = '" . $category_id . "'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $salida .= " - ";
            $salida .= utf8_encode($row["name"]);
            return $salida;
        }
        $result->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

Any Help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask